# UE4.25 - The Game has crashed and will close

Tags: crash, unreal-engine4

I've recently finished a game that I successfully packaged to Windows 64-bit but then when I ran the .exe file on another computer (the game works on my computer), the file crashes and says: `The Game has crashed and will close.` There was no error messages or logs, just that.

I searched this up on YouTube, Stackoverflow, and the UE4 Forum but nothing helped. Please help, thanks.

Comment: There's an include debug files option when packaging, which will give you a pdb for symbols. If you want logs to write, then you need to manually enable them for each module by adding `bUseLoggingInShipping = true;` to your target.cs file. You can also technically put a debug exe to packaged data too but YMMV.

Comment: I fixed it now, [this](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/37357/how-do-i-create-a-exe-of-my-game.html) answered my question.